# angular NaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined exception

Tags: angularjs

right justified and i want to have a partial view depending on which tab was clicked. found some sample code online to get me started but am unable to figure out the tabs by following a sample code

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
     <script src="scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'SearchController',
    templateUrl: 'search.html'
  })
})
```

Search.html

```
<div ng-controller="SearchController">

</div>
```

SearchController:
Sample taken from example

```
angular.module('mainApp').controller('SearchController', function  ($scope, $window) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
  ];

  $scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
    });
  };
});
```

Error:

```
[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/ng/areq?p0=search%2FSearchController.js&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like it's having trouble finding SearchController all together. Is your SearchController in its own file? If so, be sure to load it in your index.html!

So,

```
 <script src="scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="path/to/controller/SearchController.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
Ah, I see the issue. You have not yet defined "SearchController" in your app.js.

To do this -

In SearchController.js, change `angular.module('mainApp')` to `angular.module('SearchController')` Understand you are creating an angular module that is not yet apart of your 'mainApp' module.

Then, in your app.js, do `var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'SearchController']);` This will properly inject your controller into your app, and it can be used correctly by your router.

Comment: SearchController.js is its own file and i have addded it `<script src="search/SearchController.js"></script>`, issue still exists

Comment: If the app has n controllers, then each one must be defined in app.js?

Comment: If you see the `Plunker` for this `http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs`, i followed their plunker example. Theie `example.js` is almost similar to my `app.js`

Comment: Thanx you made my day much better :D

Answer (score 1):

you have forgotten to add reference in your index.html file .Please add and get it resolved

```html
    <div ng-view>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="SearchController.js"></script>
    </div>
```

you have forget add reference in you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the browser did not support ES7
I was doing

```
newjsonobj = {...jsonobj}
```

changed it to

```
newjsonobj = Object.assign({}, jsonobj, {})
```